# Grant VIEW DATABASE STATE on master DB

Tags: permissions, azure-sql-database

I am asked to provide access to `VIEW DATABASE STATE` in the master DB of an Azure SQL Server instance (Premium P6) to an external user (vendor) in order some investigation to be done.

When run "grant VIEW DATABASE STATE TO " it returns "Grantor does not have GRANT permission." When run "grant VIEW SERVER STATE TO " it returns "Securable class 'server' not supported in the server scope in this version of SQL Server".

From what I read in some articles it seems that there is no `VIEW DATABASE STATE` in the master DB, it is only available in the user's databases, am I right?

As I am new in this area (have more experience with Oracle and almost nothing with Azure SQL Server) can someone tell is it even possible `VIEW DATABASE STATE` to be granted over master DB? And is really `VIEW SERVER STATE` is not supported or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database can be a little confusing on how to provision permissions, IMO.

> From what I read in some articles it seems that there is no VIEW DATABASE STATE in the master DB, it is only available in the user's databases, am I right?

Yes, I believe this to be pretty much true, that in Azure SQL Database, it is not permitted to grant such a permission to the `master` database. Instead, the correct thing to do is apply it to the user database(s) instead that you want DMV and diagnostic information to be available for. That seems to be what is discussed in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/2272#issuecomment-510669498):

> ...you are not able to grant this permission to users in the master database...

And

> On Premium Tiers, you would be able to grant VIEW DATABASE STATE permissions to the contained user in the scoped database, and run server or database level scoped DMVs on that database.